# ASP TexhBox OnTextChanged not firing when ReqularExpressionValidator is there

Tags: asp.net, textbox

I have a text box with a RegularExpression Validator. The TextBox onTextChanged function is not getting fired if the have this RegularExpressionValidator. If the ReqularExpressionValidator is removed, the onTextChanged function fires.

Here is the sample code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt1" CausesValidation="true" runat="server" ValidationGroup="gpccheck"  CssClass="Label4" AutoPostBack=true OnTextChanged="txt1ValueChanged"></asp:TextBox>
                                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txt1"
ErrorMessage="Please Enter Only Numbers"   ValidationExpression="^\d+$" ValidationGroup="gpccheck" SetFocusOnError="true"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

My OnTextChanged function is

```
protected void txt1ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     lbl1.Text = "Value changed";
}
```

Please help

Comment: Are you entering valid data in the text box that matches the RegularExpressionValidator ValidationExpression?

Comment: Yes. I am entering valid data so that the Regular ExpressionValidator is a success. In this case they are just numbers

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txt1" ErrorMessage="Please Enter Only Numbers"   ValidationExpression="^\d+$" ValidationGroup="gpccheck" SetFocusOnError="true" EnableClientScript="False"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

i added `EnableClientScript="False"` to this tag only.
after this change, when you exit from textbox (onBlur), the page posts back to server.

Comment: That did not help. Even the RegularExpressionValidator is not working.

Comment: @Hiteshwar are you sure? i tested it Successfully.

Comment: Yes I tested it. The RegularExpressionValidator is also not throwing any error when I enter wrong values nor it is posting back to server.